Extension of derivation
Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a von Neumann algebra acting on the Hilbert space $H.$ Is it true that every derivation $\delta\colon \mathcal{A}^\prime \to \mathcal{B}(H)$ can be extended to a derivation $\tilde{\delta}\colon (Z(\mathcal{A}))^\prime \to \mathcal{B}(H),$ where $Z(\mathcal{A})$ is the centre of the algebra $\mathcal{A}$?
Recall: A linear map $\delta\colon A\to B$ where $A\subseteq B$ are two algebras is derivation if $\delta(X Y)=X \delta(Y)+\delta(X) Y$ for all $X,Y\in\mathcal{A}.$
My expectation is that the above question is not true.

Does there exist a non-inner derivation from a factor to $B(H)$? If yes, just choose $\mathcal{A}$ to be the commutant of that factor and $\delta$ to be a non-inner derivation. Then it certainly cannot be extended to $Z(\mathcal{A})’ = B(H)$ since all derivations from $B(H)$ to itself is inner.

@DavidGao thank you  for your anwer but again the existence of a non-inner derivation from a factor into B(H) is an open problem.

If all derivations are inner, then obviously they can all be extended, even to $B(H)$, so this seems to again boil down to an open problem.
